# Java dynamic downcasting from generic list

Tags: java, generics, rtti, instanceof, downcast

how i can dynamic downcast objects, with out instanceof statement?
I reading Bruce Eckel's Thinking in Java, and there using Class, and there is such a theme, but I was not approached
P.s. Sorry for my English.

```
public class GenericTest {


    static private interface Base {
    }


    static private class A implements Base {
    }

    static private class B implements Base {
    }

    static private class C extends B {
    }

    private List<Class<? extends Base>> types;
    private List<Base> objects;

    public GenericTest() {
        types = new ArrayList<Class<? extends Base>>();
        types.add(A.class);
        types.add(B.class);
        types.add(C.class);

        objects = new ArrayList<Base>(Arrays.asList(new A(), new B(), new C()));

        for (Base base : objects) {
            if (base instanceof A)
                test((A) base);
            else if (base instanceof C)
                test((C) base);
            else if (base instanceof B)
                test((B) base);

            for (Class<? extends Base> c : types)
                if (base.getClass().equals(c))
                    test(c.cast(base));
        }
    }

    private void test(A a) {
        System.out.println("A");
    }

    private void test(B b) {
        System.out.println("B");
    }

    private void test(C c) {
        System.out.println("C");
    }

    private void test(Base base) {
        System.out.println("Base");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GenericTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider using the visitor pattern.

Comment: Describe in more detail what you actually want to *achieve*. Using `instanceof` is at least dubious in most cases.

Comment: Do the posted responses answer your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes, the use of `instanceof` indicates a flaw in your design, probably by violating some basic principals of Object Oriented Programing.

In you case, I can oversee two solutions depending on what your final goal is. The first one is to encapsulate the specific behavior of `test()` in the classes `A`, `B` and `C`. It can be done by declaring a method `test()` in the interface `Base`, making it an abstract class and implementing it in the subclasses.

```
static private abstract class Base {
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("Base");
    } 
}

static private class A extends Base {
    private void test() {
        System.out.println("A");
    }
}

static private class B implements Base {
    private void test() {
        System.out.println("B");
    }
}

static private class C extends B {
    private void test() {
        System.out.println("C");
    }
}
```

Notice that classes with an hierarchy level greater than 3 are not a good practice. Inheritance is the highest degree of coupling you can get between two objects. That is why we tend to [prefer composition over inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance).

The second way to improve your design is, as @SLaks mentioned, to use the Visitor Pattern. More about this pattern can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). Recommended reading on the subject are [GOF](http://www.amazon.ca/Design-Patterns-Elements-Reusable-Object-Oriented/dp/0201633612) and [Refactoring to Patterns](http://industriallogic.com/xp/refactoring/).

Comment: I just want to separete implementetion from classes. Right now, i reading Head first design patterns.

Comment: Head First Design Patterns is a good starting point. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

It's not exactly clear what you would like to do, but here is how you can achieve the same result without casting and `instanceof`.

Put the `test` method on interface `Base`:

```
static private interface Base {
    public void test();
}
```

Then implement it:

```
static private class A implements Base {
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("A");

}
```

and similarly for `B` and `C`.
Then your loop should look like this:

```
for (Base base : objects) {
    base.test();
}
```

This will result in calling `A::test` if `base` is an instance of `A`, `B::test` if `base` is instance of `B` etc. (The method is selected based on the runtime type of the referenced object).